# How to set android tcp buffer size

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-ndk, android-networking

I have written a socket program in c. This program will send data from my android phone to my PC. Here what i need that i want to increase my data buffer size to a larger one so that i could send a large data. I used setsockopt() system call to increase the tcp buffer size. But my android not allowing me to increase the size beyond 4096 bytes. Following i pasted my Server side code. Need help

```
          int listenfd = 0;
             //Create a socket
                if((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1)
                {
                    printf("\n Could not create socket..");
                    return -1;
                }
         sock_buf_size=8192;
         setsockopt( listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,(char *)&sock_buf_size , sizeof(sock_buf_size));

         setsockopt( listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF,(char *)&sock_buf_size , sizeof(sock_buf_size));

     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
       // sock_buf_size = SOCKET_BUFF_SZ;


        //Binding the socket
        if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1 )
                printf("\nBind failed ");
        else    puts("\nBind done");




        //Listen to incoming connections
        listen(listenfd, 5);

        //Accept an incoming connection
        puts("\nWaiting for incoming connections...");
        c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c);

 if((RcvdByteCnt = recv(connfd ,pSendBuff , BuffLength, 0)) != -1)
        {
            printf("\n Revived Byte->%d",RcvdByteCnt );

        }
```

Comment: If the max buffer size is limited to 4096, send 4096-byte chunks until there is less than 4096 left to send, then send what's left.

Comment: Seems like you want to change the buffer size on the connected fd, not the listen fd.

Comment: @MartinJames The send() method does exactly that for you. You don't have to worry about the socket buffer size yourself.

Comment: @EJP, It only does that if the send buffer size is not already 0....